# how to shift group by condition in model in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent

I have a post where I want to know the number of comments on a post and want to know total number of different users on that post.

I got the number of total comments with `withCount()`, but I am stuck with a total number of different users commented on that post.

I thought to use `groupBy` but how to do that in the model itself if a question on my mind as below code i

```php
public function TotalUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(PostComment::class)
        ->select('user_id')
        ->groupBy('user_id');
}

public function TotalComments() {
    return $this->hasMany(PostComment::class)
        ->select('user_id');
}
```

`post_comments` table has the following structure:

```sql
// Post table Structure
id,
user_id,
title,
slug,
content,
status,
created_at
updated_at

// Post Comment table Structure
id, 
user_id, 
post_id, 
comment,
created_at, 
updated_at

// User table Structure
id,
name,
email,
verified_email,
password,
refresh_token,
status,
created_at
updated_at
```

The result I get in both the functions is same with `withCount()` function. even if there are multiple comments by same user on that same post. so I think `groupBy` is not working.

// edit - adding example output

```
total_comments_count: 907,
total_users_count: 907,
```

this is wrong output as one does have more than one comment on a that post.

Comment: show your db structure and explain more clear what you want to filter and how

Comment: what is the result you get for the `*_count` attribute when using `withCount()` with both relationships?

Comment: @RomanBobrik I already did but again adding it with post and user table structure too.

Comment: @lagbox for example if a post have 907 comments, the `totalusers` function also gives the same count which is incorrect as one user has commented more than one time.

Comment: so `totalcomments_count` is 907 ?

Comment: @lagbox yes it's showing that which is incorrect. my logic was to group the users based on `user_id` on that particular post. but it's not working.